# LDAP syncrepl with multiple DITs?

Tags: ldap

I have two different configurations, both of which work well. One has a single DIT, and does syncrepl multi-master replication. The other has two DITs on a single host. What I would like to do is set up a multiple-DIT configuration with multi-master replication. I have not been able to find any information on how to do so. Does anyone have pointers on where I could find info on doing this setup? (OpenLDAP on RedHat 6.8) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got it figured out.  This is the outline of the needed slapd.conf:

```
includes
pidfile/argsfile if used
loglevel if used
serverID
modules
TLS cert locations

database config
access control

database monitor
access control

database 1
suffix/rootdn/checkpoint/cache/directory
access control
indexes
syncrepl block
overlay syncprov
mirrormode true
overlay ppolicy

database 2
suffix/rootdn/checkpoint/cache/directory
access control
indexes
syncrepl block
overlay syncprov
mirrormode true
overlay ppolicy
```

Enjoy!